# IS it Possible in mysql to pass Multiple whereBetween clause for same fields?

Tags: mysql

Here this would be my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `x` BETWEEN 20 AND 80
  AND `x` BETWEEN 120 AND 140
```

?

Comment: The same single value cannot match these 2 conditions at the same time. Maybe you need in OR instead of AND between your BETWEENs?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already correct. You should try enclosing the two `Between` statements inside a parenthesis. Like this

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`x` BETWEEN 20 AND 80) AND (`x` BETWEEN 120 AND 140);
```

Or for **OR**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`x` BETWEEN 20 AND 80) OR (`x` BETWEEN 120 AND 140);
```

To make the code understandable by the compiler and by the person who will read the code.

Comment: Thanx! Will try to make it work with KnexRaw

Comment: Okay @Aviralkumar goodluck~ I hope you'll make it work. Have a nice Day!